# Adding a custom admin page

Tags: admin, admin-menu

I want to add a page of content (a readme file) in the WordPress admin, I can't seem to find how to do this in the codex - can anyone point me in the right direction? It will literally just be  a simple page with a few paragraphs of content.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need just two steps:

1. Hook into the action `admin_menu`, register the page with a callback function to print the content.
2. In your callback function load the file from `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "included.html"`.

Demo code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_91693_register' );

function wpse_91693_register()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Include Text',     // page title
        'Include Text',     // menu title
        'manage_options',   // capability
        'include-text',     // menu slug
        'wpse_91693_render' // callback function
    );
}
function wpse_91693_render()
{
    global $title;

    print '<div class="wrap">';
    print "<h1>$title</h1>";

    $file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "included.html";

    if ( file_exists( $file ) )
        require $file;

    print "<p class='description'>Included from <code>$file</code></p>";

    print '</div>';
}
```

I added an example to my demo plugin [T5 Admin Menu Demo](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Admin-Menu-Demo) to show how to do this in a sub menu and in a OOP style.

Comment: Just tried this and looks awesome but is there any way to have this in the submenu from my custom post type? as opposed to it being a menu for itself.

Comment: Ive tried 'show_in_menu' in the custom post type but this then has a menu which doesn't show the page and doesn't show "add new" for the custom post type either.

Comment: Solved! for anyone else try add_submenu_page and just add the extra parameter for parent slug, as outlined here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page