# add_query_arg not work in admin

Tags: plugins, functions, query

I have code:

```
class some{

     public function run(){

            add_filter('query_vars', array( $this, 'addPar'));   
            $this->some_body();
     }

     public function addPar($vars){

      $vars[] = "my_par"; 
      return $vars;

    }

    public function some_body(){

     if(isset( get_query_var('my_par')) {

      $value = get_query_var('my_par'); 

      echo $value;

      }

    echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url(add_query_arg(array('my_par' => '4'))).'">></a></li>'; 

    }

}
```

And `get_query_var()` not work.

**SOLUTION**

In back-end this function not work probably. I use instead `$_GET`.

Comment: I change little code but idea is the same - after click link variable is not registered in WP Query in "public query_vars".

Comment: Can you see something in debug.log?

Comment: i have define WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG and SCRIPT_DEBUG as TRUE  but i not have debug.log file in /wp-content. Plugin WP Live Debug display nothing. I testing my plugin in localhost.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest to fix this issue before, it could be really helpful.

Comment: Debug display nothing. I testing my plugin in localhost.

Comment: I would like to, but I do not know what to walk, because it happens in the administration panel, and everything is OK on the user's side.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's live or localhost that should be generated anyways. You can write in the debug file through this little function https://gist.github.com/huraji/e7543dbb91240533ce91a7d5a64b43ed

Comment: my debug file is created, but contain nothing. Maybe  i must do chmod 777 htacces file?

Comment: I can't tell: is the URL generated correctly, i.e. has the my_par, but it's just not available in WP_Query even though you've registered it with query_vars? Or is the URL generated wrong, without the my_par parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some_body` needs to be run as an action on `pre_get_posts`.

Here's an [example of the entire process of adding new query vars](https://gist.github.com/carlodaniele/1ca4110fa06902123349a0651d454057).

Pay extra attention to `myplugin_pre_get_posts`:

```
function myplugin_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
...
    $city = get_query_var( 'city' );
...
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'myplugin_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Comment: can you look in my new code?

Comment: I just saw `admin.php` in your code. If this is something you're doing in the WordPress admin, this is not the right way to do it. Take a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91693/adding-a-custom-admin-page and the WordPress Codex for Admin Pages: https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

Comment: I call "admin" in title question. I have menu and now in some in content in admin panel in my plugin i must get variables from $_GET, and of course i can do it $_GET['some'] but i want know how do it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Adding query vars is not what you should be doing here. That's for matching patterns on the front-end to map url structure to particular query arguments. This is not intended use for any of this.